# PHP Exchange Web service

Tags: php, web-services, exchangewebservices

I am using exchange web service in PHP( PHP EWS) to retrieve MS Exchange Calendar events.But am not getting the repeat rule of an event.So cannot find whether the event is recurring or not.How can I find the full details of an event? Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa565898(v=exchg.140).aspx

You have several options for defining how to return data from the server.  They are:

MergedOnly

FreeBusy

FreeBusyMerged

Detailed

DetailedMerged

Give each of these a try with a test meeting you setup on your calendar and run a print_r to see if it has the information you are looking for.